# What is the most efficient way to store the time of data entry in a table?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I like to keep track of the time when a record is entered into the table. What is the most efficient way to achieve that? From coding wise, I expect there is minimum code changes. In terms of space, I expect the smallest space in database taken by implementing such a mechanism. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going worldwide, MySQL's TIMESTAMP (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) is almost universally a good choice over DATETIME, since it stores the time as UTC instead of local time so DST changes won't cause you problems if analyzing in multiple time zones.

Having a non DST changing time zone as a base can be a life saver, converting between multiple time zones with different DST changeover dates can really cause problems, consider for example having a timestamp during the hour that happens twice in a change from summer- to winter time.

Refer this link for more explantion - http://billauer.co.il/blog/2009/03/mysql-datetime-epoch-unix-time/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So do you mean I need to define a column whose type is of TIMESTAMP to record the time when a data entry is entered in a table?

Comment: Yes,TIMESTAMP as data type depends on your implementation